# Evaluate a geometry node tree in python

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I've got a script that loads geographical data into an attribute and creates a point cloud.
[image]

The data is a 3D array so I want to use the frame to slice out different time steps.
I use this to update my attribute

`bpy.data.objects[name].data.attributes['myAttribute'].data.foreach_set('value', slice.flatten())`

Except these changes don't appear unless I re-enter my attribute here and the tree is executed again.

[image]

How can I re-execute my node tree again at the end of the script?

```
bpy.data.node_groups['Geonodes'].is_evaluated
```

always returns False so I dunno if that's relevant

Also I would like to avoid using 'ops' or 'context'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a work around.

First you can execute 'update_tag()' on the object with the geometry nodes. This usually works, however in this case it required a frame to scrub.
To get around this I wrote a function and passed it into the
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre handler and now it works wonderfully

https://gfycat.com/emotionalmerryblackandtancoonhound

heres the code:

```
def update_data(scene):
...
        bpy.data.objects[name].data.attributes['myAttribute'].data.foreach_set('value', slice.flatten())
        bpy.data.objects[name].update_tag()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(update_data)
```

Comment: had the same problems in Python [Problems with multiple calls of Geometry Nodes from a Python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/311451/problems-with-multiple-calls-of-geometry-nodes-from-a-python-script/311548#311548).