# Problems with multiple calls of Geometry Nodes from a Python script?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Each one of the following scripts (which provide different collections as input for the Geometry-Node) work as expected on their own and output different values:

***Script 1 (Isometric Reference Collection) :***

```
import bpy

from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C  
     

# specify input for Geometry Node (i.e. collection):
D.objects["Floor Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_15"]\
    = D.collections["Isometric Reference Collection"]

# retrieve comptuted output (via Named-Attribute) from Geometry Node 
H_REF = D.objects["Floor Plane"].evaluated_get(C.evaluated_depsgraph_get())\
    .data.attributes["H_MAX"].data[0].value

print("H_REF = " + str(H_REF))
```

***Script 2 (Isometric Render Collection):***

```
import bpy

from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C  
     

# specify input for Geometry Node (i.e. collection):
D.objects["Floor Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_15"]\
    = D.collections["Isometric Render Collection"]

# retrieve comptuted output (via Named-Attribute) from Geometry Node 
H_MAX = D.objects["Floor Plane"].evaluated_get(C.evaluated_depsgraph_get())\
    .data.attributes["H_MAX"].data[0].value

print("H_MAX = " + str(H_MAX))
```

However, I need both values H_REF and H_MAX in a single script, but if I combine the two above scripts to a single one then both values are the same.

***Script 3 (evaluating both collections):***

```
import bpy

from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C  
     

# specify input for Geometry Node (i.e. collection):
D.objects["Floor Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_15"]\
    = D.collections["Isometric Reference Collection"]

# retrieve comptuted output (via Named-Attribute) from Geometry Node 
H_REF = D.objects["Floor Plane"].evaluated_get(C.evaluated_depsgraph_get())\
    .data.attributes["H_MAX"].data[0].value

print("H_REF = " + str(H_REF))

# specify input for Geometry Node (i.e. collection):
D.objects["Floor Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_15"]\
    = D.collections["Isometric Render Collection"]

# retrieve comptuted output (via Named-Attribute) from Geometry Node 
H_MAX = D.objects["Floor Plane"].evaluated_get(C.evaluated_depsgraph_get())\
    .data.attributes["H_MAX"].data[0].value

print("H_MAX = " + str(H_MAX))
```

I just could duplicate the corresponding Geometry-Node with providing specific collections, but how to fix this via Python, any ideas (I use blender version 3.4)?

Comment: Please provide a (MINIFIED) .blend example for testing. [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486) Maybe you need to e.g. update the view layer...

Comment: I will try to upload a simplified blend-file which reproduces the misbeahviour, but it will take some time ...  
The hint with updating the view layer is a good starting point I guess, also see this answer relating to my problem 
[Dependency graph API changes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140802/166276), however neither solutions 
 with updates of depsgraph or view layers work.

Comment: Update : below a link to a minimized blend-file to reproduce this "misbehaviour" ...  

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=B0DSPRLB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/B0DSPRLB/)

Answer (score 1):

After some research I finally found a similar problem here [Evaluate a geometry node tree in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252801/evaluate-a-geometry-node-tree-in-python)
As we assumed, it is some **update or evaluation issue**.
The given workoround also works for me, i.e. setting a new input-value for a Geometry-Node Group needs an update in order to take effect immediately:

`bpy.data.objects["Result Object"].update_tag()`

So adjusting ***Script 3*** results in the following workaround with different output values:

```
D.objects["Floor Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_15"]\
    = D.collections["Isometric Reference Collection"]
# needs update:
D.objects["Floor Plane"].update_tag()
H_REF = D.objects["Floor Plane"].evaluated_get(C.evaluated_depsgraph_get())\
.data.attributes["H_MAX"].data[0].value

print("H_REF = " + str(H_REF))

D.objects["Floor Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_15"]\
    = D.collections["Isometric Render Collection"]
# needs update:
D.objects["Floor Plane"].update_tag()
H_MAX = D.objects["Floor Plane"].evaluated_get(C.evaluated_depsgraph_get())\
    .data.attributes["H_MAX"].data[0].value

print("H_MAX = " + str(H_MAX))
```